# Server performance and disk usage portal?

Tags: linux, windows, monitoring, system-monitoring

I'm looking for a good web based portal to install on internal production servers to give information about the health of the server to people who have no login permission for that server at the command line. Typical information would be disk capacity left, processes running status, capacity graphs for network, disk and CPU.

Ideally, the portal would support installation on both Linux and Windows servers.

Answer (score 2):

**Nagios** is an excellent tool for that job. It can provide you both health status for practically anything and graphing. It can monitor Linux, Windows, and lots of typical services you have.

Have not ever installed it on Windows, though.

Comment: one can install nagios in a linux and use NCSA agent to get stats from a windows server , for the client would be using it over the web, backend OS should not matter much unless they have some hardcore policy for OSes.

Comment: I had thought of Nagios, but I am looking for something self contained to the server. I'm not sure if that makes sense but it removes the need for a centralized monitoring server. Monitoring agents are installed on the servers but handled by another division. I'd like to be able to check the situation by myself.

Comment: @Stuart Woodward: that Nagios can scale up to large networks does not mean its more complex / heavyweight than a single node solution. However if there is already monitoring on the server, then your first port of call should be getting access to that